# Skyrim Dragons Running When Hurt?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

Okay, I've gotten alright at fighting dragons from a hiding spot with a bow- but when I manage to get their health really low they fly off! Is this because I've maxed out my sneak and they can't find me? Or is it a bug? 'Cause normally creatures don't run when they get low on health- only people. Maybe it's identifying the dragons like NPC's? Help?

Comment: How far are you seeing the dragons go? I've had instances where they just flew around above me, sometimes getting a decent bit of distance before returning. Basically, are you sure they're leaving and not just flying around? Also, I believe there is a shout which forces them to land.

Comment: The shout would be Dragon Rend, gotten in the Alduin questline

Comment: The dragons aren't just circling, otherwise I would be able to see them using whisper aura. It's happened at every dragon that has a 'nest', and I have to fast travel away and come back to fight them again. The wandering dragons just fly away. The issue isn't the dragons being in the air, I can still hit them there- they are just leaving. Getting them on the ground won't help if they aren't there in the first place.

Comment: There is a bug in the game that sometimes a dragon flies aways when is hurted, and then he comes back at you at a later time.

Answer (score 2):

When a dragons HP gets low it will land in the nearest "landing spot". But if there is no "landing spot" close by they will fly far away.

Comment: That makes some sense. Can you elaborate on what qualifies as a landing spot?

Comment: @DCShannon Not perched atop a building.  Not impaled by a tree.  They are about as skilled at hanging onto the sides of cliffs as your player.  (Oh to be a horse...)

Comment: @tjd They actually do land on buildings sometimes. The way the answer is phrased makes it sound like there are predefined landing spots. Maybe they just mean a large enough clearing.

Comment: @DCShannon What you mean to say is that they sometimes land on buildings when >50% Health.  Under 50%, they need a spot on the ground, quickly.

Comment: @tjd I did not mean to say that, because I did not know that was a factor. That would be the kind of thing that should be added in further elaboration.

Answer (score -1):

It really matters on the pc I mean as you can tell the pc's in skyrim are a little bit weird. Dragons don't usually run, and it's for sure not your sneak you just ran into a few weird pc's in the game. You'll get this more when you start facing elder dragons then you'll be the one wishing they would run.

Comment: Thank you, but I play on the Xbox, so this isn't really applicable...

Comment: @Irma97 I think he's using PC to mean NPC, not personal computer.